# Django Models: One-to-Many Relationships, Reaching Across Tables -- How Can I get All Book objects with Reviews?

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset, one-to-many, django-orm

## My Problem:

I have a handful of django models which are setup with various one-to-many relationships. I am trying to retrieve all Books which have a Review (I don't want to retrieve any books whom have no Reviews). Although what I'm trying to do seems relatively straight forward, I'm having real difficulty accomplishing my goal. It seems I may not properly understand how to reach across tables, and any advice anyone could provide in helping me better understand how to get all *all* `Book` objects which have a `Review` stored.

### My Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    """Creates instances of a `User`."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = UserManager() # Attaches custom `UserManager` methods to our `User.objects` object.

class Author(models.Model):
    """Creates instances of a `Author`."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    """Creates instances of a `Book`."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # ties us into an author for the book. if author deleted, books delete too.
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Review(models.Model):
    """Creates instances of a `Review`."""

    description = models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # ties to user, if user deleted, deletes all user reviews
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="reviews") # book for review
    rating = models.IntegerField() # user rating between 1-5
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    objects = ReviewManager() # Attaches 'ReviewManager' to `Review.objects` methods.
```

### What I've tried:

I've tried giving a `related_name="reviews"` to my `Review.book` property, and I've tried accessing reviews via `Book.objects.all().reviews_set.all()` or similar such queries, using `_set.all()` and am probably missing something / doing it incorrectly.

### Desired Goal:

Retrieve all `Book` objects, whom have a `Review` attached to them (not retrieving `Book` objects whom have no Reviews).

Can anyone help point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your time reading!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best solution for gathering all books, whom have at least one review. This seems to be accomplishing my needs and answered my original question:

```
Book.objects.filter(review__gte=1).distinct()
```

This is saying, from `Book` model, get any books whom have a review `gte` (greater than or equal to) 1 -- and make sure they are `distinct()` ie, no duplicates.